# How to configure a GRE tunnel for ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I am trying to configure a gre tunnel between two Ubuntu PCs: 1st with wlan1 interface 192.168.1.51 and 2nd with wlan2 192.168.1.2.

PC1:

```
ip link add gre1 type gretap remote 192.168.1.2 local 192.168.1.51
ip link set dev gre1 up

gre1@NONE: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1462 qdisc pfifo_fast state
UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
link/ether 92:d0:28:8b:3e:a6 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff promiscuity 0 
gretap remote 192.168.1.2 local 192.168.1.51 ttl inherit
```

PC2:

```
ip link add gre1 type gretap remote 192.168.1.51 local 192.168.1.2
ip link set dev gre1 up

7: gre1@NONE: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1462 qdisc pfifo_fast
state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
link/ether ba:09:9a:66:85:02 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff promiscuity 0 
gretap remote 192.168.1.51 local 192.168.1.2 ttl inherit
```

But when I ping from .51 to .2, I don't see any GRE encapsulation. It is just going over wlan interface.

PC1:

```
10.1.0.0/16 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.1.0.51  metric 1 
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlan1  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.51
```

Answer (score 2):

Configuration is missing IP addresses for the tunnel interfaces.

PC1: 192.168.1.51 (let say tunnel IP: 10.200.0.51)

```
ip tunnel add gre1 mode gre remote 192.168.1.2 local 192.168.1.51 ttl 255
ifconfig gre1 up
ifconfig gre1 10.200.0.51
```

PC2: 192.168.1.2 (tunnel IP: 10.200.0.2)

```
ip tunnel add gre1 mode gre remote 192.168.1.51 local 192.168.1.2 ttl 255
ifconfig gre1 up
ifconfig gre1 10.200.0.2
```

Answer (score 0):

i know this is an old question, but looking for something else, i found this and decided to answer.

Long story short, it doesn't work that way.

bit longer of an answer: both ends need separate IPs: the tunnel endpoints would get a more different IP than the WLAN addresses. So, you have 192.168.1.0/24 as your main (physical) network. you would then have, say, 10.0.0.0/24 as your virtual (GRE) network. if you give the gre1 interfaces an ip in the 10.0.0.0/24 subnet, and ping then, they will go over GRE links then. watching traffic on the wlan connections should then show you the GRE encapsulation.